# Safari shows invalid date while using moment(x).year() in DD-MM-YYYY format. while Chrome works fine

Tags: google-chrome, safari, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` with `Angular 5`.

Encountered a strange problem that with `Chrome`, it works fine but in `SAFARI` while debugging I see the values as `NaN` or `"Invalid Date"`

```
date = 18-05-2019 // DD-MM-YYYY format 

year = moment(date).year(); // getting year as "Invalid Date" or NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the format you have to moment so it know how to convert your date:

```js
let date = '18-05-2019'

let year = moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').year();

console.log(year)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Figured that Safari doesn't work well with hyphen eg. 18-05-2019
`var date = new Date(dateString);  // gives invalid date again `
So i changed the date format to 18/05/2019 and then used this:
`var date = new Date(dateString);  // works  `